# How to show " 1 new" when there is a new message when using views to override private messages block

Tags: views, privatemsg

I have private messages installed. In my project, I disabled the block that comes with the private messages module. Using views, I created a link that allows users access their private messages.

In the default private message block, the word "new" appears beside the "message link", when the user has a new message.

Please, how can I mimick this attribute in my custom message link.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the messages nodes?

Comment: The messages are not nodes. They are messages sent by one user to another using https://drupal.org/project/privatemsg

Comment: @seyi are you able to solve this. I am also searching for same.